# How to use 'sapply' or 'lapply' to count the number of lines in n csv files?

Tags: r, loops, lapply, sapply

I need to write a function that takes 2 arguments: `directory` and `id`. `directory` is essentially the working directly of R. `id` is the name of the file. All files have extension `csv` and a name between 001 to 332.

The function should return a data frame with two columns: `id` and `nrow`. `id` is the name of the file, and `nrow` is the number of rows in that file.

I started with the following codes but this will only work with if the there is only 1 `id` get passed to the function:

```
directory = 'specdata'
id = 1 # this should be able to take a list of numbers i.e. 1:332
id1 = if(nchar(id) == 1) {paste("00",id,sep="")}
      else if (nchar()== 2) {paste("0",id,sep="")})
file = paste(directory,"/",as.character(id1),".csv", sep="")
data = read.csv(file)
casenum = nrow(data)
output = c(id1, casenum)
```

How can I modify the codes so that the function can repeat itself if more than 1 `id` is passed. For example the line `id = c(1,2,3,5,6)` is getting passed?
I am thinking of using `lapply` or `sapply` but don’t know where to start.
Thanks,

Comment: Perhaps you could modify the question's title to reflect the problem, maybe something along the lines of 'count the number of lines in each file in a specified directory'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If you just want to have the number of lines in each file, then I'd actually recommend using the command line tool `wc`: it will be much faster.
  `wc -l *.csv` will give you an ASCII table with the number of lines in the first column and the file name thereafter.
  (`wc` for the Windows command line is available e.g. as part of the [GNU core utilities](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm).)
- If it is about doing something for *each* .csv file in the directory, use
  `file = Sys.glob (paste0 (directory, "/*.csv")`

Anyways, here's what you asked for more specifically:

```
directory = 'specdata'
id = 1:17

file = sprintf ("%s/%03i.csv", directory, id) # now a vector with file names

casenum = sapply (file, function (f) nrow (read.csv (f)))

cbind (id, casenum) 

# or, if you prefer a data.frame

data.frame (id = id, casenum = casenum)
```

Comment: Please consider showing the code that would be used with the command line tool `wc`.

Comment: @cbeleites - thanks! this got what I needed, but a few questions for my own learning: a. what does ""%s/%03i.csv" mean? b. can the results to be returned with only 2 columns 'id' and 'casenum'? Now it is also returning the file path as the 1st col. c. is the result a data.frame? or how to make it a data.frame? thanks again!!!

Comment: @PerriMa: `sprintf` syntax: `%s` puts in a character, `%i` prints an integer number to ASCII. The `%03i` means that the integer should be printed with at least) 3 digits and should be zero padded at the beginning to those 3 digits. See either `? sprintf` would have told you that.

Comment: @PerriMa: no, the result has only 2 columns. What you perceive as 1st column are the rownames.

Answer (score 2):

While not necessary, it's easier to read if you wrap up the operations in a named function.  That can be within another function:

```
countall <- function(directory, ids) {
  countlines <- function(id) {
    ## Your code, copied from the question
    id1 = if(nchar(id) == 1) {paste("00",id,sep="")}
      else if (nchar(id)== 2) {paste("0",id,sep="")}
    file = paste(directory,"/",as.character(id1),".csv", sep="")
    data = read.csv(file)
    casenum = nrow(data)
    ## No need to attach the id here, as you can use the names
    return(casenum)
  }

  retval <- lapply(ids, countlines)  # or sapply, to return a vector instead of a list
  names(retval) <- ids

  return(retval)
}
```

Run with:

```
countall('specdata', 1:10)
```

Comment: Doesn't id have to be the first argument to countall? Plus, don't you need, e.g., `lapply(id,countlines,"mydirectory")`

Comment: @jlhoward Look at the signature for the order of arguments.  As for the second question, `directory` is a variable in the environment of `countlines` and thus need not be passed in to lapply.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg - a couple edits (I don't know how to make it to your original post): a). `id` is missing in `else if (nchar()..` b). there is an extra `)` at the end of the same line. Also, I ran with your code with `countall('specdata',1:10) and got the error message ` cannot open file 'specdata/.csv': No such file or directory`. It looks like the id didn't get pasted after 'specdata/`?

Comment: @PerriMa I just copied the code from the question and didn't notice the syntax errors.  Thanks, I fixed these.  The missing `id` in the `nchar` call probably caused the error (when the loop got to 10).